# Color balance formula adding too much white

Tags: javascript, math, colors, html5-canvas

I am trying to write color balance, but I am having some difficulties with the math. I found this formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance#Scaling_monitor_R.2C_G.2C_and_B)

[image: Color Balance Formula]

What I have done is the following:

1. Get individual sums of all the reds, greens and blues
2. Get an average for each red, green and blue channel
3. Lastly I apply the formula on each channel of each pixel and set it back to the ImageData on the canvas

   - `(255 / col.red) * avgRed`
   - `(255 / col.green) * avgGreen`
   - `(255 / col.blue) * avgBlue`

It looks like this:

```
function averageColor() {

  let sumRed = 0, sumGreen = 0, sumBlue = 0
  let pixels = 0

  // Get the sum of each color
  this.eachColor((col, idx) => {
    sumRed += col.red
    sumBlue += col.blue
    sumGreen += col.green
    pixels++
  })

  // Get the averages of each channel
  let avgRed = sumRed / pixels
  let avgGreen = sumGreen / pixels
  let avgBlue = sumBlue / pixels

  // Replace each color in the image
  this.eachColor((col, idx) => {
    this.setColorAtIndex(idx, color.rgb(
      (255 / col.red) * avgRed,
      (255 / col.green) * avgGreen,
      (255 / col.blue) * avgBlue
    ))
  })

}
```

Here are the two functions seen above (`this._dta` is an `Uint8ClampedArray` from `ImageData.data`):

```
function eachColor(callback) {
  for (let i = 0, n = this._dta.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    callback(this.getColorAtIndex(i), i)
  }
}

function setColorAtIndex(index, color) {
  this._dta[index] = color.red
  this._dta[index + 1] = color.green
  this._dta[index + 2] = color.blue
  this._dta[index + 3] = color.alpha
}

function getColorAtIndex(index) {
  return color.rgb(this._dta[index], this._dta[index + 1], this._dta[index + 2], this._dta[index + 3])
}
```

When I apply the filter, this is what the before and after look like, as you can see there is too much white. What is wrong with my formula?

### Example Before

[image: Color Balance Before]

### Example After

[image: Color Balance After]

Comment: I'm not sure to get neither how the code relates to the formula as explained in the wikipedia article (where is the  white reference pixel?) nor how is the image related. (it looks more like a negative effect than a color balance, which, if unintended, would probably point to an inversion of the channels somewhere in the hidden part of the code, maybe due to TypedArray misuse?)

Comment: @Kaiido That was my initial thought, the color is not adding too much white, it is inverting the colors in the image. I feel like the calculations are correct but its pulling the red, blue and green colors with a # mistake.

Comment: I thought the  was the average `avgRed`, `avgGreen`, `avgBlue`. I updated the code with the other methods.

Comment: No, according to wikipedia's article you linked to  is "*a pixel which is believed to be a white surface in the image before color balancing"*. The average color is unlikely to be white...

Comment: So... How would I get the average white of the image or should I say ?

Comment: Yes, don't say *average*, because it's more *reference* but not average. And to do so, softwares generally offer a pick-a-color option. You could also try to set it to some hard-coded values, or maybe to the whitest color in the image.

Comment: They do, but they also have the **Auto White Balance**, and in GIMP you don't have to select a color to do so...

Comment: Hard coding a white color `240` seems to work: `(255 / 240) * col.red`

Comment: I got it looking exactly like GIMP!  in the first loop you only want the colors where `if (col.luminance >= 60)` then you do `(255 / avgRed) * col.red` and set that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to multiple by the average. You want to scale the average so the largest value is 255. This is essentially pretending the the average color should be grey and then scaling. So if your average was `[133.54055621951161, 133.85785501369506, 95.50769969447687]` then white could be:

```js
let avg = [133.54055621951161, 133.85785501369506, 95.50769969447687]
let max = Math.max(...avg)
let white = avg.map(c => 255 * c / max)
console.log(white)
```

Once you have that you can use it to scale it by the formula (in practice you should gamma correct this transformation (srgb gamma is about 2.2, the inverse is about .45:

```
 data[i]     = (255/white[0]) ** .45 *  data[i] ;     // red
 data[i + 1] = (255/white[1]) ** .45 *  data[i+1]; // green
 data[i + 2] = (255/white[2]) ** .45 *  data[i+2] // blue
```

You can see that all this is doing is scaling everything by the ratio of `[255, 255, 255]/whitepoint`, which depends on the average being close gray. In this case it does a pretty good job removing the yellow cast.

Here's what it looks like for me after the transformation:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]